# Setting an array to zero on a specified list of indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, zero

Let `f_1` be an array of shape `(a,b)` and f_2 an array of shape `(2*a,b)`. `f_2` equals `f_1` if we restrict the array on even rows. I want to set `f_2` to zero to everywhere where `f_1` is zero. I tried the following:

```py
I = np.argwhere(f_1 == 0)

for x in I:
    x[0] = 2*x[0]

f_2[I] = 0
```

but `LA.norm(f_2)` results in `0.0` so this approach apparently doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can multiply the indices by two for the first dimension with:

```
i,j = np.where(f_1 == 0)
f_2[2*i,j] = 0
```

Comment: `argwhere(...).T`?? Any reason not to just use `where`?

Comment: @PaulPanzer: no, just started from the attempt in the question :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use slicing to select even columns and boolean indexing to set zeros.

```
f_2[::2][f_1==0]=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply do something like this?

```
for x in I:
    f_2[2*x[0]][x[1]] = 0
```